# Specify order of nunit tests running on teamcity

Tags: c#, nunit, teamcity

Is it possible to specify the order in which nunit tests are run in teamcity?

If yes, how to do that? These tests are data heavy, and I want to avoid populating the data for them each time. The data is populated in the testfixture, and if ordering works, I don't need to setup my data for each test.

Comment: Does it really take that long to populate the data? Have you considered changing your infrastructure to have a quicker way of testing? Depending on ordering in unit tests is a really bad idea in general.

Comment: The data setup involves populating different business objects with millions of records, and a few other things. These tests are actually to measure the performance of a few areas in code, which can be tested after the BOs have been set up.

Comment: If these are performance tests, I wouldn't expect them to be run quite as often as genuine unit tests... but I'd prefer them to be as "clean" as possible. It would be bad if some sort of cache-warming from one test unwittingly affected another test, for example.

Comment: Not disagreeing with previous comments, but for the purpose of the question: If memory serves then NUnit runs tests alphabetically on a per assembly basis; so if this is still the case then a prefix would hack this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the comments, the tests are executed alphabetically. However, I did not want to rename the tests with prefixes such that they ran in some particular order. And taking into consideration Jon's comment, I moved data setup to test setup from test fixture.